# holomorphic line bundle over germ of complex space

Tags: complex-geometry, holomorphic-bundles

I wonder if holomorphic line bundle over zero of holomorphic function(over $\mathbb{C}^n$) is trivial?(We can assume it to be a manifold if necessary)

I Know there is a principle that, for Stein manifolds, we can reduce the classification of holomorphic bundle to the classification of topological bundle. But I have no idea to obtain any information about the topological data.

Thank you for your answer!

*Some backgrounds:

We say a space is complex if it is locally  the zero set of holomorphic function over $\mathbb{C}^n$. We define the germ of space $(T, t_0)$ as the equivalent class of those spaces $(S, s_0)$ such that there exist two isomorphic neighborhood $U$ of $s_0$ and $V$ of $t_0$.

The book I read state something like: holomorphic line bundles over germ of complex space are holomorphically trivial.

The book doesn't give a explicitly definition about bundle over germ of space, so I understand the statement above as: holomorphic line bundles over zero of holomorphic function is holomorphic trivial.

Comment: Germs of analytic varieties are contractible and smooth bundle over contractible manifolds are trivial.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Why germ of analytic variety is trivial? I know it is true when the t_0 is regular, i.e. the holomorphic function have invertible differential at t_0, but how to prove it when the differential of holomorphic function is degenerated at t_0? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Every real-analytic variety is homeomorphic to the geometric realization of a simplicial complex, see for instance

*Łojasiewicz, Stanisław*, [**Triangulation of semi-analytic sets**](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=ASNSP_1964_3_18_4_449_0), Ann. Sc. Norm. Super. Pisa, Sci. Fis. Mat., III. Ser. 18, 449-474 (1964). [ZBL0128.17101](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0128.17101).

In particular, if $A\subset {\mathbb C}^n$ is a complex-analytic subvariety, then every point $p\in A$ has a contractible neighborhood in $A$.

2. Now, to your question: Suppose that $V\to A$ is a holomorphic vector bundle. By the definition (I am taking here the weakest definition possible), this bundle is locally trivial as a smooth vector bundle. Since $A$ is locally a Stein space, you can now quote Oka-Grauert principle,

*Grauert, Hans*, [**Analytische Faserungen über holomorph-vollständigen Räumen**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01351803), Math. Ann. 135, 263-273 (1958). [ZBL0081.07401](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0081.07401).

This principle implies that if a holomorphic vector bundle over a Stein space is smoothly trivial, then it is holomorphically trivial. Thus, holomorphic vector bundles over analytic varieties are locally holomorphically trivial.